# How to run single maven test with spaces within name

Tags: maven, groovy

Normally using maven when I want to run a single test I would do something like this....

```
mvn clean test -Dtest= GetRegistrationValidatorTest#MyTestName
```

We have just changed our Groovy test names to be more meaningful using the following type of syntax.

```
class GetRegistrationValidatorTest {
    @Test
    void 'validation get registration chassis number success'() {

    }
}
```

How can I run the single maven test when it is named as per above?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using both types of apostrophes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn clean test -Dtest='GetRegistrationValidatorTest#MyTestName'`

Single quotes work for me, even with stranger characters than spaces:

```
class PlopTest {
    @Test void 'Hey! Can you plöp?'() {
        println "Sure..."
    }
    @Test void foo() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
% mvn test -Dtest='PlopTest#Hey! Can you plöp?'
[...]
Running PlopTest
Sure...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.91 sec
```

1 test run, no failure => it correctly executed *only* the single test I passed as argument.

If I try `-Dtest='PlopTest'` it runs both tests (and of course fails).